# Compiling Cinnamon

Tags: cinnamon

I am trying to build Linux Mint's cinnamon DE on Ubuntu 14.04 but I get this error on the `make` command, can someone help?

```
  CC       libst_1_0_la-st-bin.lo st/st-bin.c: In function 'st_bin_set_child':st/st-bin.c:465:7: error: 'clutter_actor_unparent' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/clutter-1.0/clutter/deprecated/clutter-actor.h:58): Use 'clutter_actor_remove_child' instead [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
   clutter_actor_unparent (old_child);
   ^
st/st-bin.c:475:7: error: 'clutter_actor_set_parent' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/clutter-1.0/clutter/deprecated/clutter-actor.h:54): Use 'clutter_actor_add_child' instead [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
   clutter_actor_set_parent (child, CLUTTER_ACTOR (bin));
```

This is for a Raspberry Pi 2B (armhf proc)

Anyway I'm trying to reinstall `clutter` now see if it helps

Comment: `-Werror=deprecated-declarations`? Maybe inspect the makefile or configure script to see how you can disable that flag.

Comment: I made a backup so if something goes wrong i don't have to worry :D i'm going to try make -k first, see if everything goes well, if not, i'll try your idea

Comment: I see the problem
`'clutter_actor_set_parent'`  is indeed deprecated since version 1.10 of clutter, but somehow the code still uses 1.08

Comment: Tried what you said but it didnt work, still get the error

Comment: The same error? How did you remove the flag?

Comment: i removed it from the `cflags` in `config.status`, buuut i just saw it put it back in, so i removed it once more and now i get `makefile error 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moorkai/cinnamon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Then log out and press on Ubuntu button like here:

[image: login image]

Then select `cinnamon`.

Comment: You don't need `cinnamon` ppa to install it. `apt-get install cinnamon` is enough.

Comment: Problem is that i cant, i am compiling it for a raspberry pi 2B like i did with kde plasma

Comment: this isn't compiling from source